# Regex search doesn't find elements with content

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

I've got the following code:

```
import re

vars='"NAME=Product","TYPE=","VERSION=1.2","VISIBILITY=","SRC=","FOLDER=TRUE","Text=foo, containing, commas"'
list = re.findall(r'\w+=".*?"', vars)

for i in range(1,len(list)):
   print list[i]
```

The output looks like this:

```
VISIBILITY=","
SRC=","
```

However I'd like to find(split) all arguments even those containing commas themself.
The output should look like this instead:

```
"NAME=Product"
"TYPE="
"VERSION=1.2"
"VISIBILITY="
"SRC="
"FOLDER=TRUE"
"Text=foo, containing, commas"
```

What do I have to change about my regex?

Comment: Aside: this looks a lot like a row of a quoted CSV file.  If so, it's probably a better idea to use the `csv` module to separate it into each term-- that'll handle the quoting correctly.

Comment: its not but thanks for the hint

Comment: You really want to avoid using `list` as a variable name; you are masking the built-in type now. You can also forgo the `range()` there and loop over the list directly: `for i in somelist: print i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression seems to be expecting the quotes around the value to the right of the `=` equals sign only, but your input has the quotes around the whole expression.

Adjusting is easy:

```
re.findall(r'"\w+=.*?"', vars)
```

Running that on your example input that gives:

```
>>> re.findall(r'"\w+=.*?"', vars)
['"NAME=Product"', '"TYPE="', '"VERSION=1.2"', '"VISIBILITY="', '"SRC="', '"FOLDER=TRUE"', '"Text=foo, containing, commas"']
>>> for match in re.findall(r'"\w+=.*?"', vars):
...     print match
... 
"NAME=Product"
"TYPE="
"VERSION=1.2"
"VISIBILITY="
"SRC="
"FOLDER=TRUE"
"Text=foo, containing, commas"
```

Comment: Also, `vars` and `VARS` are different variables

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you need a regex:

```
[i for i in  vars.split('"') if i not in ',']
```

out:

```
['NAME=Product',
 'TYPE=',
 'VERSION=1.2',
 'VISIBILITY=',
 'SRC=',
 'FOLDER=TRUE',
 'Text=foo, containing, commas']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is closer to what you'd really want:

```
 list = re.findall(r'"(\w+)=(.*?)"', VARS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSV to do this:

```
import csv

vars='"NAME=Product","TYPE=","VERSION=1.2","VISIBILITY=","SRC=","FOLDER=TRUE","Text=foo, containing, commas"'
reader=csv.reader(vars,delimiter=",",quotechar='"')

print [''.join(tgt) for tgt in reader if ''.join(tgt)]
```

Prints:

```
['NAME=Product', 'TYPE=', 
 'VERSION=1.2', 
 'VISIBILITY=', 
 'SRC=', 
 'FOLDER=TRUE', 
 'Text=foo, containing, commas']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

vari=('"NAME=Product",'
      '"TYPE=","VERSION=1.2",'
      '"VISIBILITY=","SRC=","FOLDER=TRUE",'
      '"Text=foo, containing, commas"')

print '\n'.join(re.findall('"[^"=]+=[^"=]*"', vari))
```